# VSC, how to change "Split Editor" to horizontal?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to be able to edit the same file while reading lines way ahead of current line. Given nowadays we do chaining, this vertical is **not** what I want

[image]

What I want is the other way.

It took me heck of time to find out the name "workbench.editor" something who controls it. But VSC version update erased it. It can't be found at setting now. Current VSC 1.38.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to rebind the split editor command, try this in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{                         // unbind the default split keybinding
                          // probably unnecessary to do this but I suggest it
  "key": "ctrl+\\",
  "command": "-workbench.action.splitEditor"
}

{                        // reset the split command to horizontal split
  "key": "ctrl+\\",
  "command": "workbench.action.splitEditorDown"
}
```

It won't have any effect on the action of the split editor icon - it is unclear if that is what you want.

Changing the keybinding will result in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> now splitting horizontally instead of to the right.

---

As @Jeb50 pointed out in the comment, you can change the split editor icon appearance and functionality by `Open Side by Side Direction` setting.  This is demonstrated below:

[image: split editor direction setting]

Comment: in fact, go `Settings` -> type `workbench`, it's the one says `Workbench > Editor: Open Side By Side Direction`. Once change it from `right` to `down`, you'll see the corresponding icon at upper right corner changed from vertical split to horizontal.

Comment: Nice, I did not know that you could actually change the icon's look and function!!  Do you mind if I put that into my answer, it needs to be promoted for more visibility.

Comment: go right ahead, even better if you do a screenshot! :)

Answer (score 0):

Select View > Editor Layout >  Split Down.

There are many options.

[Example Here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9DdSm.png)